# paypal error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure in laravel

Tags: paypal

error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure in paypal.
it was working fine suddenly but i got this error. i tried everything but didn't find any solutions at all... please help me

Comment: Is there a reason why you are still relaying on SSLv3? It is not recommended to use, and I think paypal isn't supporting it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

SSL3 had some major vulnerabilities [discovered by Google,](https://security.googleblog.com/2014/10/this-poodle-bites-exploiting-ssl-30.html) thus a  mandate from a security standpoint was presented heavily last year; which PayPal required SSL3/2 types to be upgraded to TLS 1.2. It is Also set to change again in June. [See here for guidance](https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&id=FAQ1914&pmv=print&impressions=false&viewlocale=en_US) on that.

Hope this helps!